# React when pass data to child throw props data duplicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I'm create Activities function component  and call child function  component called Categories  when i send categories list to Categories function  component and log "props" data send twice first one is empty and second has data as follow

Activies

```
function Activities() {
 const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);

  function handelChange({ target }) {
    setCategory({
      ...category,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    });
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories().then((_categories) => setCategory(_categories));
  }, []);

 return (<Categories category={category} onChange={handelChange} />)

}
```

and categories component

```
function Categories(props) {
 console.log(props);

return (<div></div>)
}
```

i'm trying to log props in useEffect **but problem still exist**

Comment: you cannot attach `onChange` event to a Component, it acts as a prop.

Comment: That's correct behavior. `Categories` component was rendered 2 times (as props, `category` changed), first at start it was rendered with `[]` and second with values.

Comment: @Deda props are just props to react. When you send it to `div` it has pre-defined handling for it and it binds it in a specific way. For a custom component, you just need to cascade it and drill it to the place you want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of how the life cycle in React works. This is correct and expected behavior. Before you load the categories, it is a blank array on the initial render. Then it gets the categories, updates the state, and re-renders, this time with categories.

- renders with the initial state(empty)
- goes and fetches categories
- re-renders with the categories

This is entirely expected. That double log is the initial render and then the updated state render. Remember React is a heavily async library. The `useEffect` doesn't happen during render, it happens after render. Every state update will also cause an update and thus another log. It might be helpful to research what will cause a React render and how the life cycle behaves.

Comment: Thank you, I understood what you are saying. But what is the best way to display category  data

const [category, setCategory] = useState(getCategories().then((_categories) => setCategory(_categories)))

OR

in category comoponent check if props not empoty like that 


  const categoriesList = [ ];

  useEffect(() => {
    setCategory(props.category.categories);
    if (category)
      category.map((cat) => {
        categoriesList.push({
          key: cat.categoryid,
          obj: <Category category={cat} />,
        });
      });
    
  });

Comment: I got it   const [category, setCategory] = useState({ items: [], isLoaded: false });

Answer (score 0):

I think you `handleChange` function should update item in a array of object not change the state object completely

```js
  function handelChange({ target: {name, value} }) {
    setCategory(categories => {
      const categoryIndex = categories.findIndex(pr => pr.id === id);
      const category = categories[categoryIndex];

      return [
        ...categories.slice(0, categoryIndex)),
        {
          ...category,
          [name]: value,
        },
      ...categories.slice(categoryIndex + 1))
    ]);
  }
```